# C - Merging 2 linked lists into the first - unexpected output

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

Edit 2: I thought of using a pointer to previous node *pre1 and *pre2, with pointer to current node *cur1 and *cur2. But I will prefer not to because 1) it is quite confusing, and 2) I feel I will be unable to maintain the code after some time has passed.

Edit 1: Added insertNode function

I have 2 linked lists of integers and I am trying to insert values from the second into the first at alternate positions, so index 0, 2, 4 etc will be integers from linked list 1 and 1, 3, 5 etc will be from linked list 2.

**Input**

Linked list 1: 1, 2, 3

Linked list 2: 99, 88, 77

**Supposed Output**

Linked list 1: 1, 99, 2, 88, 3, 77

Linked list 2: Empty

**Instead I am getting**

Linked list 1: 1, 2, 3

Linked list 2: 99, 88, 99, 88, 77

That is, my code is inserting into llist2 even though I passed llist1 into the function (and haven't written code for llist2 at all).

---

I have the functions createMerged and insertNode

```
void createMerged(LinkedList *llist1, LinkedList *llist2);
```

Its inputs are the 2 linked list, and modifies them.

---

```
int insertNode(LinkedList *llist, int index, int value);
```

It is a black box function which will insert a new node with *value* at the given *index* (first index is 0) into the given *linked list*

---

**This is my code now**

```
int main() {
    createMerged(&llist1, &llist2); 
    printf("Linked list 1: ");
    printList(&llist1);
    printf("Linked list 2: ");
    printList(&llist2);
}

void createMerged(LinkedList *llist1, LinkedList *llist2) {
    int curIndex = 0;   //Counter for while loop
    ListNode *cur1, *cur2;      
    cur1 = llist1->head;
    cur2 = llist2->head;

    if (llist1->size == 0 || llist2->size == 0) return;    //empty list

    while (cur1 != NULL) {
        if (curIndex == 0) {

 //Odd output here!
        insertNode(&llist1, 1, cur2->item);  //if index is 0, insert into 1    
        } else {
        insertNode(&llist1, curIndex * 2, cur2->item);  //else, insert into index*2
        }
        cur1 = cur1->next;
        cur2 = cur2->next;
        curIndex++;
    }
}
```

insertNode is a black box function which works without any issue. It is from the book *Computer Science* by Forouzan and Gilberg

```
int insertNode(LinkedList *llist, int index, int value){

    ListNode *pre, *cur;

    if (llist == NULL || index < 0 )
        return -1;

    // Insert in empty or as first node
    if (llist->head == NULL || index == 0){
        cur = llist->head;
        llist->head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        llist->head->item = value;
        llist->head->next = cur;
        return 0;
    }

    // Inserting in middle
    else {
        cur = pre->next;
        pre->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        pre->next->item = value;
        pre->next->next = cur;
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

To recap: I am passing llist1 into insertNode, but somehow it modifies llist2 even though I have not called llist2 in the code at all.

Comment: Since it seems you don't really have a great reason not to other than that you think it works, I would suggest posting the code for `insertNode` as well.

Comment: Your output appears to show the node with value 88 having two different successors.  That cannot be the case at any one time, so probably you have generated duplicate nodes.

Comment: Consider the specification and signature for `insertNode()`: it inserts a ***new*** node into the target list.  That's not at all what you want if you're trying to merge the existing nodes into a single list.  To the extent that you rely on `insertNode()` for this, it looks like you are pursuing an entirely wrong strategy.

Comment: @MichaelMior I have added the insertNode code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the advice. I considered using pointers to previous and current node for both lists, so *pre1, *cur1, *pre2, *cur2. But `insertNode()` code does the same, just encapsulated within the function.

Comment: What you've provided is still not an MCVE ([MCVE]).  The first statement in your `main()` is to call `createMerged()` on two lists for which you've not shown the definition, so they must be file scope (global or static) variables, and have presumably been magically initialized.  You've not shown code that attempts to print the lists before the merge.  You've not shown code that prints the merged list.  You've no way to get at the merged list properly from outside the `createMerged()` function; you simply hack at the list 1 that's passed to your function.  Your merging structure is odd, too.

Comment: @Jackson, you are entirely missing the point.  `insertNode()` manipulates node pointers as, yes, you should do.  But it ***inserts a* new *node***.  That has no part of any process wherein you are *rearranging* nodes of two lists to form a single list.